# Multiple kernels with Atom Hydrogen

Tags: plugins, ipython, atom-editor, hydrogen

I want to use several different, separate IPython kernels simultaneously on different files in Atom with the Hydrogen plugin. By now I can use Hydrogen, it works perfectly, but the same kernel is used for all files (so I cannot run several files at the same time).

I am aware of the discussion here: https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/40 but I have difficulty understanding which method I should use and putting it into practise. Guess it is still a bit under development.

In particular, I can use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and search for [hydrogen select kernel], but then I only see one entry called [Python 2]. I do not find any command to open new Python2 kernels (in order to get, for example, to choose between [Python 2 inst 1], [Python 2 inst 2], etc).

So my question is:

Is there a simple way to open several distinct instances of a Python 2 kernel in Hydrogen?

If not, has somebody a good method to suggest (would be nice to have description of detailed steps) for using simultaneously several kernels in Hydrogen?

Comment: Yeah I wish it was one kernel per file too, there's no way to do this currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Hydrogen 2.0 adds this feature (I have not tested it yet though):

https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/releases/tag/v2.0.0

> Three commands to start a new kernel:
>
> "Start Local Kernel" (default when executing code in a new file)
>
> "Connect to Existing Kernel" (replaces "Switch Kernel")
>
> "Connect to Remote Kernel"